# Why elements are fading and animating without hover? (on load)

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, translation

When i load the page first time, the div fading and border-radius animating 0 to 50px without any reason!! it's only happening when i adding the css externally, please help me please. I need to complete a project as fast as possible

**Live Demo** http://toastbyayan.rf.gd/ (Use incognito mode with cache off because you guys know about infinityfree)

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wtfooooook.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="yol"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.yol {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: 2s;
}

.yol:hover {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

**P.S.** I also tried with localhost in different browsers, when i trying to load or reload the page, everytime happing this problem. (I am using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve))

Comment: The CSS Transition is happening as the page loads, forcing to load the transition only after the page has been loaded, should fix it, Try this. https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/

Comment: still animating

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to say which transition do you want to animate.
Here the CSS code:

```
.yol {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition-property: width, border-radius;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.yol:hover {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```